# How do I add a delete row button to json generated table record?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, json

I have a table created using JSON and I want to add a button to the row to choose to delete that record from the database that it is sourced from.

How do I make this button functional?

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th>FirstName</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th><th>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = "api2.php";
    $.getJSON(url,function(json){
        $.each(json,function(i,dat){
            $("#myTable").append(
                '<tr><td>' + dat.firstName + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + dat.lastName + '</td>' +
                '<td><form><input type="button" value="Delete Record" class="button"></form><br><form><input type="button" value="Edit Record" class="button"></form></td></tr>'
            );
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I would also like to give functionality to the edit record button if someone is able to help with that.

Comment: add a css class to the button markup and possible a data-id attribute then you can add an event listener to that button class that will be assigned to that line.  Simpler withjQuery if that is a possiblity

Comment: Isn't the JSON temporary for displaying on the website? Don't you really just want to delete the DB record then the JSON wont have the record?